# javascript: How to convert dates entered in text fields to Date Format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have 2 text fields `txtDateFrom` and `txtDateTo`.
How can I convert the values from these fields to Date format, so I can calculate the number of days between DateFrom and DateTo?

I'm using the datepicker and when dates are selected they are in the `mm\dd\yyyy` format

This is my function:

```
function ValidateDateDiff(sender, args) {
     var dateFrom = $('#cphBody_ExcessAuth_txtDateFrom').val();
     var dateTo = $('#cphBody_ExcessAuth_txtDateTo').val(); 

     var dateDiff = dateFrom - dateTo;
}
```

Comment: what exactly is "date format"? is the format they're in not already date format? looks like a date to me....

Comment: What datepicker? jQuery UI has built in ways to get date objects etc.

Answer (score 0):

you could using jqueryUI.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker.parseDate( "mm\dd\yyyy", "09\20\2016" );
```

See this page for details: 
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not answering questions I just guessed..

```
var date = "03/15/1997";
var parts = date.split("/");
var date = new Date(parts[2]-1, parts[1], parts[0]);
alert(date.toLocaleFormat());
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/e6mp0cgy/

As noted in the comments if you're using jQuery you can get the date object directly from jQuery. Otherwise check out [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Moment](http://momentjs.com/) to parse the values from the fields:

```
var dateFrom = moment($('#cphBody_ExcessAuth_txtDateFrom').val(), 'MM/DD/YYYY');
var dateTo =  moment($('#cphBody_ExcessAuth_txtDateTo').val(), 'MM/DD/YYYY'); 

var dateDiff = dateTo.diff(dateFrom, 'days');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function ValidateDateDiff(sender, args) {
     /*
     var dateFrom = $('#cphBody_ExcessAuth_txtDateFrom').val();
     var dateTo = $('#cphBody_ExcessAuth_txtDateTo').val();
     */

     // for test
     var dateFrom = "01\\01\\2016"; // date in format mm\dd\yyyy
     var dateTo = "01\\05\\2016"; // date in format mm\dd\yyyy

     var dateFromSplit = dateFrom.split("\\");
     var dateToSplit = dateTo.split("\\");
     var dateFromDate = new Date(dateFromSplit[2]+"-"+dateFromSplit[0]+"-"+dateFromSplit[1]);
     var dateToDate = new Date(dateToSplit[2]+"-"+dateToSplit[0]+"-"+dateToSplit[1]);
     var timeDiff = Math.abs(dateToDate.getTime() - dateFromDate.getTime());
     var daysDiff = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); // days difference
     return daysDiff;
}
```